# Can NotA (none of the above) class be combined with object detection / segmentation models?

Tags: classification, object-detection, object-recognition

So there's this way of classifying an object as NotA (none of the above) class as described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02830
So mostly this uses a sort of confidence thresholding with different approaches.

**Can a classifier with such a NotA class be used as part of an object detection framework?**

I'm assuming if the classifier isn't trained on a background class then NotA would "light up" also on background, so that class might need to be added as well to make some sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so a bot is asking me for clarifications? We live in the future, don't we